# Convert JSON data into String

Tags: ruby, json

Hi I am converting JSON data into String. Please find the JSON data below. I am facing an issue where in the system is unable to convert NULL values into string. Therefore, I am getting the following error: can't convert nil into String (TypeError)

JSON DATA:

```
{"success":true,"message":null,"data":null}
```

Code Used:

```
c = Curl::Easy.new(Configuration.fetch("<URL where we can find the above JSON DATA and nothing else>"))
#    c.follow_location = true
#    c.http_auth_types = :basic
#    c.username = Configuration.fetch('auth_user', false)
#    c.password = Configuration.fetch('auth_pass', false)
#    c.headers["User-Agent"] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17'
#    c.perform
     result=JSON.parse(c)
     puts result["Success"]
```

Please help.

Comment: Show us your current attempt that is producing the error.

Comment: I have edited the issue. Hope you can see the code now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
puts result["success"]
```

You have a capital S where you need a lower case one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my effort failed. I got a new error      "can't convert Curl::Easy into String (TypeError)."

Comment: You can try to edit your code in an IRB session first. It will tell you after every step, what it makes of what you entered.